# Updating/Reassigning values field in :let Variable in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a proper way to edit a variable created by :let and call it?

```
describe "#create" do

let(:animal_payload) {
    {
      "data": {
          ...... 
          "animal_type": {
            "data": {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "sea",
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }

  let(:land_animal_payload) {animal_payload}
  :land_animal_payload["data"]["animal_type"] = {data:[{"id":1, "type":land}]}

  context "when animal is type land" do
    subject { post :create, params: land_animal_payload }

    it "should create a land animal" do
        ....
      end
  end
```

I have a very large payload called animal_payload. I just want to change the field animal_type and call a post on it. However, when I call this:  `:land_animal_payload["data"]["animal_type"] = {data:[{"id":1, "type":land}]}` I get:

```
`undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I use the same payload but change one of the fields slightly so that I can call it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to do is use a let variable inside the let variable:

```
describe "#create" do
  subject { post :create, params: animal_payload }

  let(:animal_payload) {
    {
      "data": {
        ...... 
        "animal_type": {
          "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "type": animal_type,
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }

  context 'when sea animal' do
    let(:animal_type) { 'sea' }

    it "should create a sea animal" do
      ....
    end
  end

  context 'when land animal' do 
    let(:animal_type) { 'land' }

    it "should create a land animal" do
      ....
    end
  end
end
```